# Why is WKWebView failing to open .doc from Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, mime-types

I have a `WKWebView` loading url from Firebase stored documents. While it successfully loads `.pdf` or `.xls`, it always fails when I try to open a `.doc` file. (error message: `This file cannot be previewed, it might be corrupted or of an unknown file format`).

Is there a way to add a `mimetype` parameter when loading the `URL` ? I'm pretty sure I did add the right `mimetype` parameter when uploading the `.doc`.

Any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

WKWebView has method `load(_:mimeType:characterEncodingName:baseURL:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415011-load

But as I remember you would need at first to download file and then pass it as a data to that method in order for DOC file to be shown.

Comment: I might have to download the file locally and open it this way since I can't seem to find any other way to open the .doc firebase url sadly :(